# How to remove a specific contact from the mobile connect held list and resend an SMS?

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, bounce-management

Is there a way to choose a specific contact number that has entered the Mobileconnect held list, so we can resend him an SMS?

I only found this one:
[Disable Bounce Logic and Clear Held Numbers in MobileConnect](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_moc_disable_bounce_logic.htm&type=5)

But that way I will delete the entier held list, where I wish to do that with only one.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here's how I did it

1. 1 You have to go to Mobile Connect Manage --> Contacts
2. In there search for the subscriber
3. Go to membership and look for the opted-out number
4. Click on Edit and change the status

Hope that helps